# Why isn't this HTML/Javascript code working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a program which helps me find the reverse of a number. So, if I enter the number 135, it gives back 531 to me. I created the code, with the help of various online sources that confirm that my method is correct. However, I cannot seem to create a solution. I tried using a while loop in a similar fashion, as well. The output always comes out as Infinity. Is there a problem with my technique or the code.

```html
<input type="button" value="Find the Reverse of a Number" onclick="inv()">
<script>
  function inv() {
    var n = prompt("Enter a number: ");
    var rev = 0;
    for (; input !== 0;) {
      var lastDigit = input % 10
      rev = rev * 10;
      rev = rev + lastDigit;
      input = input / 10;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: One thing is that you don't have `input` variable, please check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it .

```js
var a = prompt("Enter a value");
var b, sum = 0;
var z = a;
while(a > 0)
{
  b = a % 10;
  sum = sum * 10 + b;
  a = parseInt(a / 10);
}
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function inv(){
    var n = prompt("Enter a number: ").toString();
    n = [...n].reverse().join("");
    alert(`Reversed ${n}`)
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Find the Reverse of a Number" onclick="inv()">
```

Comment: OP is specifically asking what is wrong with their code. (Also, prompt returns a string. There is no need for `toString()`)